# Database structure for versioning and multiple languages

Tags: database, versioning, nlp

How can I solve the issue of content existing in multiple versions and multiple languages?

My current structure:
[image]

Each content can only have one active version in each language, and that's how I'm curious on how to best solve.

Right now I have a column of the *contentversions* table, which means for each change of active version I have to run a update and set *active=false* on all version and then a update to set *active=true* for the piece of content in question.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a table `activeversion` with the same structure as `content_contentversion_languages`, but with a unique key on `(content_id, language_id)` and a single foreign key on all columns, referencing `content_contentversion_languages`. Marking a new version as active requires just a single INSERT or UPDATE to this table.

Comment: Good idea! Does the table structure look sensible otherwise? I've been hoping on interating this into an ORM which I'm sure requires some sense in the structure :)